# Jenkins Shared Library Immutable Singleton

Tags: jenkins, groovy, singleton, immutability

I have a Singleton patter class in my Jenkins shared library:

```
public class Configuration {

    private static final INSTANCE = new Configuration()

    static getInstance() { return INSTANCE } 

    private Configuration() {
    }

    def initialize(env, params) {
        Foo = params.FOO;
    }

    public String Foo = ''
}
```

Later I can call this from elsewhere using something like this:

```
Configuration.instance.initialize(env, params);
config = Configuration.instance;
println 'FOO: ' + config.Foo
```

Ideally, I want the benefit of the Singleton pattern, but I don't want some fields to be overridden by consumers.

**First Attempt:**

On first thought, I would think this would work:

```
public class Configuration {

    private static final INSTANCE = new Configuration()

    static getInstance() { return INSTANCE } 

    private Configuration() {
    }

    def initialize(env, params) {
        INSTANCE.@Foo = params.FOO;
    }

    public final String Foo = ''
}
```

**Error:**

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the property 'Foo' because the backing field is final.

**Second Attempt:**

On Second thought, I would think initializing in the constructor would work, however I don't seem to have access to `params` and `env`, unless these are passed in from the vars function, via the `initialize()` method.

How can I make this Singleton class immutable, or its fields read only?

Answer (score 0):

I think you Could:

1. Define your class with "implements Serializable", as documentation advices.
2. Implement the constructor that would accept 1 parameter of type BaseScript, and pass `this` to it upon instantiation, relative to **that** `this` (which you could call internal `script`) you can refer to `script.params`, `script.env`, etc. and I mean you don't HAVE to use `initialize`, you can do all you want in the c'tor.

But wait, please tell more:

why does CI/CD code need to have a Singleton?
You're passing its data as parameters [so it's not really an immutable entity :)]

Maybe you could "simply" create an immutable map out of your parameters....

Configuration as singleton feels as if you can delegate configuration management to ... configuration management service (consul, etcd, or others).

Please elaborate, it's very curious!

Also you referred to something as "consumers". are these library consumers? or people running the jobs?

Thank you!